# How to browse files on a Motorola Defy (Android) with ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, files, usb-connection-mode

I want to browse files on my mobile with ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

**Android 2.1 (Eclair)**

1. Plug in your phone
2. Pull the notification bar; tap on "USB connected (Select to copy files to/from your computer)". Tap "Mount".
3. Ubuntu should autoprompt you to browse the phone using File Manager (Nautilus)

[image: eclair usb notification]
[image: eclair usb mounting]

**Android 2.2 (Froyo) (and *probably* Android 2.3)**

1. Plug in your phone
2. Android should autoprompt you to enable USB Mass Storage.
3. Ubuntu should autoprompt you to browse the phone using File Manager (Nautilus)

[image: froyo usb mass storage]

(Froyo image shamelessly taken from http://droidfreeapps.com/2010/05/usb-mass-storage-tweaks/)